# How to check date validity with only year and month?

Tags: sql-server

The column is in `varchar`, with values such as 201510. I want to check if these entries are valid year and month.

Comment: you should use either a date field or separate `smallint` columns for year and month for easier validation checks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `isdate` function.

```
SELECT  isdate(tValue+'01')
FROM (
        SELECT '201510' AS tValue
        UNION
        SELECT '201513'
    ) t
```

`Isdate` Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value; otherwise, 0.
You can simply convert your year month to date by adding a day '01' to you value. ie `'201510'+'01' = '20151001'`

In your case.

```
SELECT isdate(column_name+'01') FROM table_name
```

Comment: Good logic on adding 01

Comment: Hi @abdul, Please explain the logic behind how the value 0 or 1 comes.